# Tricker chain rule with partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{d}{dt} f(x(t)g(t))\bigg)$$

I begin substituting $y=xg$ and get

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{df}{dy} (y(t))\cdot (x'(t)g(t)+x(t)g'(t))\bigg)$$

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x\partial y}(y)\cdot (x'(t)g(t)+x(t)g'(t))+\dfrac{df}{dy}(y)\cdot(x''(t)g(t)+g'(t))$$

How could I improve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=x(t)$ and assume that $x$ is invertible.  Then, from the chain rule

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}&=\frac{d x'(t)}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{dx'(t)}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{x''(t)}{x'(t)}
\end{align}$$

Now, with $x(t)$ invertible, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d }{d x}\frac{df(x(t)g(t))}{dt}&=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{df(x(t)g(t))}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac1{x'(t)}\frac{d^2f(x(t)g(t))}{dt^2}\end{align}$$

And the rest is left to the reader.

Comment: Thanks once again!!

Comment: You're welcome.  It's always a pleasure.